# Getting SVN Error during operations: "bad record MAC"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to checkout a folder on my companies svn server.

I am getting this error using Tortus SVN (version

```
Command: Update  
Error: REPORT of '/svn/REPOSITORY/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read response body: SSL   
Error: error: decryption failed or bad record mac (https://svnroot:8443)  
Finished!:
```

Tortoise SVN Version info:

```
TortoiseSVN 1.6.12, Build 20536 - 64 Bit , 2010/11/24 20:59:01
Subversion 1.6.15, 
apr 1.3.8
apr-utils 1.3.9
neon 0.29.5
OpenSSL 0.9.8p 16 Nov 2010
zlib 1.2.3
```

I thought that the problem origionally might be with my SVN client so I tried doing a checkout using Subversive (Eclipse SVN plugin).  I got a similar error message:

```
Checkout operation for 'https:<you know all that stuff...>' failed.
svn: bad record MAC
svn: REPORT request failed on '/svn/REPOSITORY/!svn/vcc/default'
```

I am not sure what my next step should be.  Often before I get the error it will complete some operations so by doing continuous updates I can checkout the entire project but this is a major pain in the ass.

Suggestions?

---

**Update:**

I just upgraded my TortoiseSVN to:

```
TortoiseSVN 1.6.16, Build 21511 - 64 Bit , 2011/06/01 19:00:35
Subversion 1.6.17, 
apr 1.3.12
apr-utils 1.3.12
neon 0.29.6
OpenSSL 1.0.0d 8 Feb 2011
zlib 1.2.5
```

This upgraded my version of OpenSSL.  Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [seems to be a bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=338006) in openssl 0.9.8. Since 0.9.8d is [numerous](http://www.openssl.org/news/) vulnerabilities, you should really consider updating to openssl 1.0.0e.

Comment: I have seen that in a couple places.  Do I just need up upgrade openssl on my local machine or do I need to update on the server too?

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude The bug report mentions that it only occurs when both endpoints are using libssl 0.9.8. Due to the mentioned security issues, it's a good idea to update both though.

Comment: I upgraded my openssl by upgrading Tortoise but still getting the same issue.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude Mmm. While it can't hurt to update the server, too, it might be something else then. Can you reproduce the problem on another computer, with just Windows and TortoiseSVN installed? Does it occur with the command-line client, too? Some "security" products [can also cause this problem](http://fixunix.com/openssl/525780-decryption-failed-bad-record-mac.html).

Answer (score 0):

Setting the IDEA_JDK_64 environment variable to a Java 1.7 JDK solved it for me. Maybe because that JDK has an updated cacerts.